# Unable to Install Openssh-Server on Ubuntu Server

Tags: permissions, ssh, dpkg, openssh, debconf

I am trying to install OpenSSH-Server and receiving following error,

```
Unpacking openssh-server (from .../openssh-server_1%3a5.9p1-5ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 17: exec: /usr/share/debconf/frontend: Permission denied

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a5.9p1-5ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a5.9p1-5ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb
```

I am running `apt-get install openssh-server` as a root user.

Comment: Looks more like UI configuration issue. Try running as sudo instead of root.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the permissions flag for program execution was removed on `/usr/share/debconf/frontend`. You can set it back with:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/debconf/frontend
```

However, this may be the symptom of some broader underlying issue of a corrupted packages and it would be better to reinstall the `debconf` package (to which `/usr/share/debconf/frontend` belongs):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall /usr/share/debconf/frontend
```